# Mixing global functions and class member functions C++

Tags: c++

Is it bad to call global functions from member functions of a class?  I mean is this ok...

```
class MyClass
{
    void print_numb();
};

int get_numb()
{
   return 10;
}

void MyClass::print_numb()
{
     cout << get_numb() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, are you looking for stylistic advice?

Comment: i think it will be better to have namespaces, rather than dangling stuff around.

Comment: "bad"?  If it were than anytime you called `cout << my_data` from within a class would also be "bad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely OK from the technical point of view: free-standing functions, global and static, are part of the language. There is no reason not to use them.

It is also OK stylistically: the Standard C++ Library provides free-standing functions, so the designers of the language were definitely OK with the idea of mixing member and non-member functions.

Of course you should take advantage of the C++ features that let you isolate your functions from functions in the libraries to which you link - by reducing their visibility to a single translation unit, or by placing them in a namespace.

Answer (score 5):

If `get_numb()` is only used by a source file implementing `MyClass` then I'd put it in an *anonymous namespace* in that source file:

```
namespace /*no name here means the namespace is anonymous*/ {
    int get_numb()
    {
       return 10;
    }
}
```

That hides it away. I prefer that to a static private function in the class since it reduces the amount of stuff in the class declaration.